# Is there any performance difference in following unsafe array indexing?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

```
long* array = stackalloc long[50];

1) array[10]

2) *(array + 10)
```

So should I replace for second version because its faster or they are the same once we got a pointer?

Comment: well if they will be different I guess my question can be changed to "why" are they different then. Hmm you said they will be different, now thats gone.

Comment: re "if" - I deleted an earlier comment where I mistakenly thought you were comparing pointer performance to vector performance - sorry if that added confusion. The two pointer approaches shown should be pretty-much identical.

Comment: okay well my tests werent showing difference but I am really desperately looking for perfromance gain so .. =)

Comment: that should work pretty darned fast. If it isn't *fast enough*, you would have to be a lot more specific about what it is doing *with* the data.

Comment: im doing pretty complex stuff 1894107877200 times so everything counts..

Comment: wanted to thank you for protobuf.net for a while, thanks for that Marc. Simply great work.

Comment: It isn't different.  Just look at the generated IL with ildasm.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two records are basically the same, just two ways of writing. Of course #1 is better, because it looks better :)